# NYTimes Article Search API - UndefinedError: 'unicode object' has no attribute 'repsonse'

Tags: python, json, unicode

I'm having some trouble with the NYTimes Article Search API.
I'm using the python package "NYTimesArtcile" and I'm trying to work with a simple example just so I can become comfortable/familiar with passing data to webpages from the NYTimes.

here's my app.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
from nytimesarticle import articleAPI

api = articleAPI("*****")

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = '*****'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = '*****'
app.config['MYSQL_CURSORCLASS'] = 'DictCursor'
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '*****'

mysql = MySQL(app)

from views import *

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here's where my view for a "featured page":

```
@app.route('/featured', methods=['GET'])
def featured():
    results = api.search(q = 'Obama')
    return render_template('featured.html', results=results)
```

Here's my html page, featured.html:

```
{% extends 'base/base.html' %}

{% block body %}

<div class="container">

<table class="table table-sm table-light">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">title</th>
      <th scope="col">URL</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for result in results %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{result.title() }}</td>
      <td>{{ result.title() }}</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>

</div>


{% endblock %}
```

I've placed results.title() in the jinja formate because it's the only thing that works. When I return results.title(), I get the first 3 objects from the JSON data (status, response, copyright). What I want is the title of the article and the web_url.

I know that the info I want is in results.response.docs, but when I try that, I get the above error.

Here's a bit of the JSON from NYTimes (one article). Any help is appreciated:

```
{
  "status": "OK",
  "copyright": "Copyright (c) 2017 The New York Times Company. All Rights Reserved.",
  "response": {
    "docs": [
      {
        "web_url": "https://www.nytimes.com/2017/12/01/books/review/peter-baker-obama-the-call-of-history.html",
        "snippet": "Peter Baker’s “Obama: The Call of History” is a tribute to a man and an office.",
        "print_page": "53",
        "blog": {},
        "source": "The New York Times",
        "multimedia": [
          {
            "rank": 0,
            "subtype": "xlarge",
            "caption": null,
            "credit": null,
            "type": "image",
            "url": "images/2017/12/03/books/review/03GOODMAN1/03GOODMAN1-articleLarge.jpg",
            "height": 397,
            "width": 600,
            "legacy": {
              "xlargewidth": 600,
              "xlarge": "images/2017/12/03/books/review/03GOODMAN1/03GOODMAN1-articleLarge.jpg",
              "xlargeheight": 397
            },
            "subType": "xlarge",
            "crop_name": null
          },
          {
            "rank": 0,
            "subtype": "wide",
            "caption": null,
            "credit": null,
            "type": "image",
            "url": "images/2017/12/03/books/review/03GOODMAN1/03GOODMAN1-thumbWide.jpg",
            "height": 126,
            "width": 190,
            "legacy": {
              "wide": "images/2017/12/03/books/review/03GOODMAN1/03GOODMAN1-thumbWide.jpg",
              "widewidth": 190,
              "wideheight": 126
            },
            "subType": "wide",
            "crop_name": null
          },
          {
            "rank": 0,
            "subtype": "thumbnail",
            "caption": null,
            "credit": null,
            "type": "image",
            "url": "images/2017/12/03/books/review/03GOODMAN1/03GOODMAN1-thumbStandard.jpg",
            "height": 75,
            "width": 75,
            "legacy": {
              "thumbnailheight": 75,
              "thumbnail": "images/2017/12/03/books/review/03GOODMAN1/03GOODMAN1-thumbStandard.jpg",
              "thumbnailwidth": 75
            },
            "subType": "thumbnail",
            "crop_name": null
          }
        ],
        "headline": {
          "main": "Remembering President Obama",
          "kicker": null,
          "content_kicker": null,
          "print_headline": "The 44th",
          "name": null,
          "seo": null,
          "sub": null
        },
        "keywords": [
          {
            "name": "subject",
            "value": "Books and Literature",
            "rank": 1,
            "major": "N"
          },
          {
            "name": "creative_works",
            "value": "Obama: The Call of History (Book)",
            "rank": 2,
            "major": "N"
          },
          {
            "name": "persons",
            "value": "Baker, Peter",
            "rank": 3,
            "major": "N"
          },
          {
            "name": "persons",
            "value": "Obama, Barack",
            "rank": 4,
            "major": "N"
          },
          {
            "name": "subject",
            "value": "United States Politics and Government",
            "rank": 5,
            "major": "N"
          },
          {
            "name": "subject",
            "value": "Presidents and Presidency (US)",
            "rank": 6,
            "major": "N"
          }
        ],
        "pub_date": "2017-12-01T17:03:19+0000",
        "document_type": "article",
        "new_desk": "BookReview",
        "section_name": "Book Review",
        "byline": {
          "original": "By JAMES GOODMAN",
          "person": [
            {
              "firstname": "James",
              "middlename": null,
              "lastname": "GOODMAN",
              "qualifier": null,
              "title": null,
              "role": "reported",
              "organization": "",
              "rank": 1
            }
          ],
          "organization": null
        },
        "type_of_material": "Review",
        "_id": "5a218b6a95d0e0246f219b14",
        "word_count": 625,
        "score": 5.197477,
        "uri": "nyt://article/78a2b8f7-430c-516e-8b37-cba782db31de"
      },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to navigate the response object to get the data you are looking for since it is not at the top level.  Looking at the JSON data I would try this:

For the webURL

```
results.response.docs[0].weburl
```

For the title

```
results.response.docs[0].headline.main
```

Comment: THANKS!! I guess I had to walk away and take another look at it. Really appreciate the help

Comment: How would I iterate through all of the JSON response objects (each article in the query)

Comment: There is one `response` object which contains a `docs` array of articles.  Therefore you would loop through the articles by `docs[i]` where `i=0...(arraysize-1)`.  ie `docs[0]`, then `docs[1]`, then `docs[2]`, etc.